# Integrate SonarQube in Bamboo for react js application

Tags: reactjs, sonarqube, continuous-integration, bamboo

I am trying to integrate react js app in sonarqube with Bamboo by running ant configuration.

```
sonar -Dsonar.host.url=${bamboo.sonarqube_host_url} -Dsonar.login=${sonarqube_auth_token} -DCommandLineParameter=${bamboo.buildKey} -Dsonar.projectVersion=3.0 -Dsonar.sources=src -Dsonar.tests=src/test  -Dsonar.exclusions=src/assets/**/*.js, src/utils/**/*.js, src/test/**/*.js, src/store/**/*.js -DBranchType=${bamboo.planRepository.branch} -Dsonar.projectName=testProject]
```

But it's failing with
Target "sonar.host.url=sonarqube.....com" does not exist in the project "My Project".

Q1. Is this the right way to do this? (As Ant is for Java)
If not how should I so this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using an Ant task to run your scan doesn't make sense since you don't user/need Ant in Javascript development. The better alternatives would be to:

1. Call the sonarqube scanner from a shell script task
2. use the 'Sonar for Bamboo' pluging (a for pay plugin) to have a more GUI-like interface to ostensibly the same thing.

You should look at the sonar scanner documentation https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN